# Align powershell results to the left

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have the following script:

```
Get-Acl 'c:\folder' | Select -ExpandProperty Access | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

What should I add to make text align to the left?

I've tried google search and it did not work out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original output**:

```
Get-Acl -Path  'C:\folder' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access |
    Select-Object -Property IdentityReference,
        FileSystemRights,
        AccessControlType, IsInherited
```

> ```
> IdentityReference                           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IsInherited
> -----------------                           ---------------- ----------------- -----------
> BUILTIN\Administrators                           FullControl             Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                              FullControl             Allow        True
> BUILTIN\Users                    ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users         Modify, Synchronize             Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                  -536805376             Allow        True
> ```

***What should I add to make text align to the left?*** Try concept of [calculated properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) (applied merely to the `FileSystemRights` property in the following example):

```
Get-Acl -Path 'C:\folder' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access |
    Select-Object -Property IdentityReference,
        @{Name='FileSystemRights';Expression={"$($_.FileSystemRights)"}},
        AccessControlType, IsInherited
```

> ```
> IdentityReference                FileSystemRights            AccessControlType IsInherited
> -----------------                ----------------            ----------------- -----------
> BUILTIN\Administrators           FullControl                             Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM              FullControl                             Allow        True
> BUILTIN\Users                    ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Modify, Synchronize                     Allow        True
> NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users -536805376                              Allow        True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default formatter in PowerShell, if you want something different, you need to alter the formatter or use the format-* cmdlets, string formatting, or create custom objects (like calculated properties, hash tables, et al) of the results and format as you'd like.

['format powershell cmdlet output'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27format%20powershell%20cmdlet%20output%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27format%20powershell%20cmdlet%20output%27&sc=0-33&sk=&cvid=8C09FBCE35644925A17F1536F021A221)

['format powershell Format operator'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27format%20powershell%20Format%20operator%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=04fa341866434ee5b79a8316c0b5980d&sp=-1&pq=%27format%20powershell%20format%20operator%27&sc=0-35&qs=n&sk=&cvid=04fa341866434ee5b79a8316c0b5980d)

> The -f Format operator
>
> A   Alignment.
> A positive number will right align n characters.
> A negative number will left align n characters.
>
> Left and right align text:
>
> "|{0,-10}| |{1,10}|" -f "hello", "world" |hello     ||     world|

So, for example, combining the calculated property and the -F operator gives you this... (btw, you can see below I am using dot reference vs -ExpandProperty to get the data.)

```
(Get-Acl -Path  'D:\temp').Access | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'IdentityReference ';Expression = {$PSItem.IdentityReference}},
@{Name = 'FileSystemRights ';Expression = {"{0,6}" -f $PSItem.FileSystemRights}},
@{Name = 'AccessControlType ';Expression = {"{0,5}" -f $PSItem.AccessControlType}},
@{Name = 'IsInherited';Expression = {"{0,6}" -f $PSItem.IsInherited}}
# Results
<#
IdentityReference                             FileSystemRights  AccessControlType  IsInherited
------------------                            ----------------- ------------------ -----------
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                           FullControl       Allow               False     
BUILTIN\Administrators                        FullControl       Allow               False     
...
#>
```

Or PSCustomObject, like this...

```
ForEach ($AclObject in (Get-Acl -Path  'D:\temp').Access)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IdentityReference = $AclObject.IdentityReference
        FileSystemRights  = ($AclObject.FileSystemRights).ToString()
        AccessControlType = ($AclObject.AccessControlType).ToString()
        IsInherited       = ($AclObject.IsInherited).ToString()
    }
}
# Results
<#
IdentityReference                             FileSystemRights AccessControlType IsInherited
-----------------                             ---------------- ----------------- -----------
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                           FullControl      Allow             False      
BUILTIN\Administrators                        FullControl      Allow             False
...
#>
```

Or this...

```
ForEach ($AclObject in (Get-Acl -Path  'D:\temp').Access)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IdentityReference = $AclObject.IdentityReference
        FileSystemRights  = "$($AclObject.FileSystemRights)"
        AccessControlType = "$($AclObject.AccessControlType)"
        IsInherited       = "$($AclObject.IsInherited)"
    }
}

# Results
<#
IdentityReference                             FileSystemRights AccessControlType IsInherited
-----------------                             ---------------- ----------------- -----------
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                           FullControl      Allow             False      
BUILTIN\Administrators                        FullControl      Allow             False
...
#>
```